# How to ask where someone just came from?

Tags: phrase-request

I have one question almost meaning like this "where are you coming from?" but not ask country or state or province, it is not long way long time. It is short way and just happening. It is more definition place which someone just coming from. Like office or marketplace or home....etc. so how could I say ?

Comment: You probably want to ask *Where have you [just] come from?* Or *Where **did** you just come from?* (effectively the same meaning). Tone of voice would be important in a real-world context, but in a *written* context it's more important to make sure you include ***just***, because otherwise it might be understood as simply an expression of surprise (implying the other person suddenly appeared out of thin air), rather than a genuine enquiry.

Comment: Your question title has the answer: "Where have you just come from?"  **just** means "just now".  In other words, you want to know their most recent location. They might say "I was at home and came straight here" but they also might say "I took the elevator from the lobby".  So you may have to clarify what you mean.  "now" is not narrowly defined.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you might be thinking of:

> "Where were you?"

You would ask this when you wanted to know where someone was most recently.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to ask where someone has just returned from would be:

> Where have you been?

However, it is important to get the tone correct. Like any question, it could sound overly interrogative, nosy, or even accusatory. To avoid sounding that way, some might prefer to ask something like "*have you been out?*" which allows the other party to offer as much detail as they wish.